# Importing OS MasterMap data into PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, import

I’m trying to import OS BoudaryLine MasterMap data into PostGIS through QGIS. I'm able to import all the files except a couple of them, which returns the error as below:

```
Error 6 
Feature write errors: Creation error for features from #-9223372036854775808 to #-9223372036854775808. 
Provider errors was:  PostGIS error while adding features: ERROR:  Geometry type (MultiLineString) does not match column type (LineString)
```

When we import any geometry data via QGIS, the table structure and datatype get created automatically based on the selected file. Below screenshot shows the PostGIS datatype in QGIS.

[image]

[image]

is there any setting on QGIS or POSTGIS to make PostGIS to accept both LineString and MultiListString geometry Type?

Comment: What format are you starting with from Ordnance Survey GML?

Comment: the file format is .gz

Comment: OS Translator also throwing the same error,

Comment: try https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/354333/276

Comment: Just make the column a multi line string

Comment: I tried with the following SQL statement; but it doesn't works.                                                 ALTER TABLE  public."BoundaryLine_SX1575"
        ALTER COLUMN geom
            TYPE geometry (LineString, 27700)
            USING ST_Multi(geom);

Comment: please [edit] your question with the new details and an explanation of what didn't work